# jquery.hoverdir.js not loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I have a problem with a direction aware hower effect. On a test page is working fine, but when I'm embedding the thumbs into the big site is not working. Please assist! you can check it at http://www.psyhealth.ro/test/index.html.
I;ve started from the code posted on : http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/

here below you can see my actual code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/patratele.css" />
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.97074.js"></script>
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/noJS.css"/></noscript>
</head>
<body>
                        <ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/7.jpg" />
                        <div><span>text 1</span></div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/9.jpg" />
                    <div><span>text 2</span></div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/10.jpg" />
                    <div><span>text 3</span></div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/11.jpg" />
                    <div><span>text 4</span></div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/12.jpg" />
                    <div><span>text 5</span></div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="h#">
                        <img src="images/1.jpg" />
                    <div><span>text 6</span></div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/2.jpg" />
                    <div><span>text 7</span></div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/3.jpg" />
                    <div><span>text 8</span></div>
                    </a>
                </li>

            </ul>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.hoverdir.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $(' #da-thumbs > li ').each( function() { $(this).hoverdir({
                hoverDelay : 75
            }); } );

        });
    </script>
```

the same code works perfect in the standalone page, but in the big site it does not work.

Comment: you are using many version of fancybox and also 2 version of jQuery Library .Use only one .

Comment: It worked. It seems it's a problem with fancy box. Thanks Tushar Gupta !

Comment: yep. It works as soon as I disabled <script src="javascript/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>.  I loaded .8.0 and also 1.8.3 version of Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

> You are using many version of `fancybox` and also 2 version of `jQuery` Library .
>   Use only one version .